# Help with mysql join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Can I get some help with a MySQL JOIN?

Basically I have 4 tables, traders, streetaccounts (that are associated with a trader), recommendation_brokerages and recommendations. I need to get all the traders names and email addresses from the traders table, where the traders streetaccount.brokerage_id exists in the recommendation_brokerages table and in the recommendations table.

Here is the basic structure of my tables.

```
tbl_traders
--------------------------------------
trader_id | trader_name | email
--------------------------------------

tbl_streetaccounts
--------------------------------------
trader_id | brokerage_id
--------------------------------------

tbl_recommendation_brokerages
--------------------------------------
recommendation_id | brokerage_id
--------------------------------------

tbl_recommendations
--------------------------------------
recommendation_id | published
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: What have you got so far? (and you should have expected this comment after more than 30 questions)

Comment: You should post the full definition of your tables especially the primary and foreign keys.  We're just having to guess at the relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t.* from tbl_traders t
inner join tbl_streetaccounts s on t.trader_id = s.trader_id
inner join tbl_recommendation_brokerages rb on s.brokerage_id = rb.brokerage_id
inner join tbl_recommendations r on t.recommendation_id = r.recommendation_id
```

NB, it is generally considered "not useful" to have a prefix that describes type.  This practice from the 80s has been often criticized.

See the section "I'm hungary" in this post by Joel http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Comment: Won't this return the trader multiple times if they have multiple street accounts?

Comment: @cope360 Yep it will.  A `distinct` before `t.*` should fix that.  Would be faster than a sub-query.

Comment: Faster than a subquery? My experience is that a `NOT IN (SELECT ... WHERE ...)` is usually faster, if the subquery does *not* reference rowdata (so that it is evaluated once for all rows, and not once per row).

Comment: Unless the optimizer is super-human (DB2?) Joins are faster than a subquery. (see mysql's own doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/rewriting-subqueries.html)

Comment: Just have to do add the DISTINCT keyword and this query works for me! Yeah I hate table or even variable prefixes, this is an existing project that I had to pick up and complete. Nothing like working through somebody else's code... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `tbl_recommendation_brokerages.recommendation_id` is a foreign key to `tbl_recommendations.recommendation_id`, we don't need to join to `tbl_recommendations`.

```
SELECT
    t.trader_name, 
    t.email
FROM
    tbl_traders t
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            tbl_streetaccounts acct,
            tbl_recommendation_brokerages rec
        WHERE
            acct.brokerage_id = rec.brokerage_id
            AND acct.trader_id = t.trader_id
        )
```